# How to convert cmsamplebuffer to data and vice-versa

Tags: swift, core-video, core-media

I want to convert cmsamplebuffer to data and again data to cmsamplebuffer for transferring it from one device to another through server

```
func frameData() -> NSData {

        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)
        let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)
        let nsdata = NSData(bytes: src_buff, length: bytesPerRow * height)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return nsdata
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to convert data back to samplebuffer?

Comment: No i didnt. any idea will be helpfull

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: i didn't manage to convert it but i send the image and depth data, using this, let imageData = context.heifRepresentation(of: image, format: .BGRA8, colorSpace: colorSpace!,options: [CIImageRepresentationOption.avDepthData: depthdata]) and i can get depth and image data on client side. it works for me.